# Как в rust конвертировать place expression в value expressions?

Tags: rust, синтаксис

```
fn main() {
    let mut funcs: [fn() -> usize; 3] = [|| -> usize {0}; 3]; // инициализация "нулями"
    
    for i in 1..=3 {
        funcs[i - 1] = || -> u8 {to_rvalue("i")}; // функции to_rvalue нет, просто она символизирует то что мне нужно
    }
    for i in 0..=2 {
        println!("{}", funcs[i]());
    }
    
}
```

Я не понимаю как мне создавать лямбды так, чтобы использовалась переменная как value expr, а не place expr. Компилятор ругается что я замыкаю переменную и не компилирует

Comment: что такое `to_rvalue`?

Comment: Ну это функция, которой нет. Она выражает ту функциональность  которую я хочу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо вопросу не хватает контекста, либо пример не слишком удачный.

Но два разных замыкания не получится хранить в одном массиве, без использования трейта.

```rust
fn to_rvalue(val: &str) -> usize {
    1
}

fn main() {
    let mut funcs: [Box<dyn Fn() -> usize>; 3] = [
        Box::new(|| -> usize { 0 }),
        Box::new(|| -> usize { 0 }),
        Box::new(|| -> usize { 0 }),
    ];

    for i in 1..=3 {
        funcs[i - 1] = Box::new(|| -> usize { to_rvalue("i") });
    }

    for i in 0..=2 {
        println!("{}", funcs[i]());
    }
}
```